# Typescript interface property want to change optional to required depending on other property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following Typescript interface:

```
type animation = "Grow" | "Fade" | "Slide";

interface ISnackbarProps {
  open: boolean;
  autoHideDuration?: number;
  position?: position;
  variant?: variant;
  type?: AlertColor;
  animation?: animation;
  icon?: React.ReactElement;
  slideDirection?: slideDirection;
  action?: React.ReactElement;
  handleClose: () => void;
}
```

In the above interface, `slideDirection` is optional. But I want to update it **optional to required** only when the `animation` property has the `"slide"` value.

Comment: You'll need a discriminated union, not an interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with `type`. Here's an example:

```
type animation = "Grow" | "Fade";

type commonSnackBarProps = {
  open: boolean;
  autoHideDuration?: number;
  position?: position;
  variant?: variant;
  type?: AlertColor;
  icon?: React.ReactElement;
  action?: React.ReactElement;
  handleClose: () => void;
};

type SnackbarProps =
  | (commonSnackBarProps & {
      animation?: animation;
      slideDirection?: slideDirection;
    })
  | (commonSnackBarProps & {
      animation?: "Slide";
      slideDirection: slideDirection;
    });
```

You can check how this works in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-zwhz4?file=/src/test.ts).

Comment: Could you explain what's going on? Why and how this works?

Comment: TS will flag the missing `slideDirection` property only when the `animation` property has a "Slide" value assigned. Otherwise, when `animation` has any other value assigned, it will allow the `slideDirection` property to be optional. Does this help?

Comment: TS is using "union types" to get that done, you can read more about them here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types
A simple union type would be `string | number` and more complex is like the one you see above called `SnackbarProps`