# Is it possible to change typescript required or optional depending on a parameter?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the same function to query in a couple of different ways, and I would like to use typescript to enforce some parameters depending on what parameters they provide to the function.

E.g. If I pass a query, I also need you to pass these other params, but you don't have to pass the query.

Right now, I can check to see if they are passing all required parameters, but I would like to be able to enforce them as required if query is passed to the function

Example function
I would like query to be optional
but if query is passed, I want column and row to be required

```
// typescript

interface GoogleSheetsConfig {
    sheetId: string;
    query? string;
    column?: string;
    row?: string;
}

export const fetchGoogleSheet = async ({
    sheetId,
    query,
    column,
    row,
}: GoogleSheetsConfig) => {

// if query exists, include column and row
// else ignore query,
}
```

I found this answer that says it does what I'm trying to accomplish, but there is no explanation:
[Typescript interface property want to change optional to required depending on other property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70522338/typescript-interface-property-want-to-change-optional-to-required-depending-on-o)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDdv8N) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does, could you expand on your explanation a little on why it works?

Comment: My only complaint with this solution is that the error just says that the the arguments are not assignable to the parameters if I forget to add something,
Ideally it would say so and so arguments are missing

Comment: I hope that complaint is minor enough for me to ignore, since I started working on an answer for that code once you said it meets your needs.

Comment: ...hmm, and [I can't even reproduce that](https://tsplay.dev/m0x6xm), it says exactly what's missing in my IDE.  If you want someone to address a followup question you might want to post a new one, making sure that the code is a [mre] that clearly shows the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `GoogleSheetsConfig` to *either* have all of `query`, `column`, and `row` present, *or* you want it to have `query` missing (and `column` and `row` can remain [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties)).  That "either-or" sort of type is best represented in TypeScript by a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

To write that, let's take your original `GoogleSheetsConfig` type and rename it out of the way to `BaseGoogleSheetsConfig`:

```
interface BaseGoogleSheetsConfig {
  sheetId: string;
  query?: string;
  column?: string;
  row?: string;
}
```

Now we can represent the two possibilities mentioned above as two separate types.  If `query` is present, then so are `column` and `row`.  So let's specify that a `GoogleSheetsConfigWithQuery` has all three present:

```
interface GoogleSheetsConfigWithQuery extends BaseGoogleSheetsConfig {
  query: string;
  column: string;
  row: string;
}
```

Otherwise, `query` is absent.  We can't actually directly say that a property must be absent.  Instead we can say that it is *optional* (so it *may* be absent) and that its value type is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) (so it essentially *cannot* be present with a defined value). Depending on your compiler settings it may allow `undefined` to be there. That's as close as we can get; in practice it is probably good enough.  So let's define `GoogleSheetsConfigWithoutQuery` that way:

```
interface GoogleSheetsConfigWithoutQuery extends BaseGoogleSheetsConfig {
  query?: never; 
}
```

And so a `GoogleSheetsConfig` is either a `GoogleSheetsConfigWithQuery` or a `GoogleSheetsConfigWithoutQuery`:

```
type GoogleSheetsConfig =
  GoogleSheetsConfigWithQuery | GoogleSheetsConfigWithoutQuery;
```

---

Let's now look at the `fetchGoogleSheet` function:

```
export const fetchGoogleSheet = async ({
  sheetId,
  query,
  column,
  row,
}: GoogleSheetsConfig) => {    
  column.toUpperCase(); // error, might be undefined
  if (typeof query !== "undefined") {
    column.toUpperCase(); // known to be defined
    row.toUpperCase(); // known to be defined
  }
}
```

Here you can see that before we test `query`, the value of `column` might be `undefined`, while if `query` is known to be defined, then `column` and `row` are also known to be defined.

This works because `GoogleSheetsConfig` is not just a union, but a [*discriminated* union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), with `query` as the *discriminant* property, since `query` might be `undefined`, which is a "unit type" or a "[literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)", and TypeScript supports using a field as a discriminant [as long as it has a literal type in some member of the union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants).

And you're also lucky in that TypeScript supports [control flow analysis for *destructured* discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions). Before TypeScript 4.6 you'd have had to leave the function parameter as a single variable like `arg` and then check `if (typeof arg.query !== "undefined") { arg.row.toUpperCase() }`.  But now you are able to destructure its properties into separate variables, and still have the compiler track the correlation between them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QOIHtcDmANhAMoAWEEYGAwriDMAcgN4BQyyGl1AkgBMAXNzBRQBANydkARwCu0AJ4B+ERjETpXBLiLyAtiDWjxIKTKi4A7iY1mLAX3btQkWIhR5CJClRr0jMwA6sBg5ACKilBKyBAAHpAgAhhomDj4xGS8AQxMLBxcCsrqmubayLr6RqUOFVbWtVrszq7g0PBIyN5ZftR0eSFh5LjyYFHKcYkQyanoWD2+OQNBBTLFMSYgEABu0JLIAPSHyC0uYEoADl6ZS-4r+cgAvDKL2feB+aHhEzHIAD7dW7vfqfIbhUbjaJKFzsBKXXBQMCVBgaZAwagIchvPrIp7ITBKEAIZAACkK3ByggANOtobSdHpDCAGcgGrTHCIccswQQAJTPAB8bBcjOqIAAdGBcABVS7XKC0dKkvkHY5xKBWKDU5AGZjkZEAIxQ8mSECY2wEMmAMDJF2uuFtG1iAEInviAESmgTm0AQAQegUUsXMqWy+XQJVYFVqk4AaxANhAyGlyGNyB9Fv9Mi4DTDcoVUYgMaO8cT1mTqfTmb9Vq4zkcQA)